# adding a button on canvas or adding canvas on half of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a button on my activity which has a canvas. I want the user to write on the canvas and then click the button.

Here is my canvas layout -

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
        drawView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

`DrawView` class contains canvas code.
What i want to do is to add `button` at the bottom on screen so as to perform some operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your drawView to a ViewGroup ( LinearLayout or such ) alongside your button - and then  setContentView(yourViewGroup)

EDIT here a hint on how to do this:

```
@Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        LinearLayout lin=new LinearLayout(this);
        lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lin.addView(drawView);

        Button btn=new Button(this);
        lin.addView(btn);

        setContentView(lin);
        drawView.requestFocus();
    }
```